# Can a 2015 Macbook Air MagSafe 2 connector be filed down to work with a 2009 Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, magsafe, charger

The title pretty much says it all. I ordered a MagSafe 2 power adapter before realizing my MacBook Pro uses the Original MagSafe. After looking at both connectors, it appears the MagSafe 2 connector would fit the MagSafe power port if it were filed down on the edges a bit. However, I'm concerned the power delivery would not match what the computer can handle, and I don't really want to go through returning and buying a new power adapter. Likewise, I wouldn't want to destroy both the adapter and the computer at one go. Does anyone know the specs – whether these two are "electrically compatible?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just filed down my new Apple MagSafe power cord on each end and it totally works with my 2012 15" MacBook Pro.. Just found out the edges and I did a few passes over the top were the pins are and pow! It totally works

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty much sure there is some difference between MagSafe and MagSafe2 plugs. [image: Consider converter instead] Another page for overview is [right power adapter and cord](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)
from Apple. 
On other hand Apple has made it clear that an adapter with the same or higher wattage than originally provided may be used without problems. So should you have a chance to apply your MagSafe2 plug for your MagSafe notebook - imho that would work

Comment: The page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700 says what you're claiming is true if the charger is a USB-C charger.  But I cannot find Apple claiming this for non-USB-C chargers...

Answer (score 2):

There are differences between the 2 (apart from size). The Magsafe 2 supplies a different voltage. The centre pin on the Magsafe 2 is a different size. It is possible the Mac may work with a different voltage (Apple does sell adapters), but using an older Mac with the new supply seems risky.